# How to control Timer & Distribution services not consume more system resources in standalone server

Tags: 2013, performance, distributedcache, owstimer

i have a single server for staging  it installed sharepoint 2013 + Project server 2013 and it has 8 GB

this server using CPU 100 % and timer service and distribution cache service running on more memory consumption

here why only these services taking more memory and causing server busy and how to control these services to not take more system resources?

[image]

current status of CPU usage and it can be reduce if i increase RAM to 12 gb
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't minimize the utilization of a timer service or distribution service in a SharePoint server. You're only option is to increase memory to at least 16 GB (preferably 24 GB) to make your single server farm run smooth.

In my test environment I have a Domain Controller with 2 GB RAM, a SQL Server with 8 GB RAM and a SharePoint Single Server with 12 GB RAM and it works like a charm.

By the way, check that your **virtual machine** is using **4 cores** instead of 1 core (which is default).

Comment: please check the update if in crease ram to 12 gn cpu usage will be reduce?

Comment: @adilahmed You have only 1 virtual core. Try to turn off the virtual machine and change it to 4 virtual cores and see if that helps. 12 GB should work OK on average load and only one user...